# Android Application Xlarge Screen

Tags: android, user-interface

i am developing an android application. i want my application to be supported for multiple screens
and it looking good in all screens upto large.when i test my application on an emulator with size
**10.1" WXGA 1280*800 mdpi** and for all xlarge screens the screen is not looking good and also my application supports potrait-mode only.i am not able to understand why it is looking like this in xlarge screens.

**screen shot: 1024 * 600**
[image]

i dont have a device to test this application how can i solve mt problem can any one suggest me a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your app is suppose to look like, but I'm guessing your content should fit the screen better instead of being spread out having a lot of space around it.

One solution would be to have another layout file that adapts your content to the x-large screens. So in resources create a new folder called layout-xlarge and add a new xml layout file there. If its an extra large screen that one will be used instead. The drawables uses pixel-density instead of screen size so you still need all sizes for your graphics to look good. 
Good reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

A second solution would be to decided if you want to support x-large screens or not. 
Then add this to your manifest:

```
<supports-screens
 android:xlargeScreens="false"
 />
```

Comment: i created a layout-xlarge file but it is not taking that xml file

Comment: if you have res/layout/main.xml it needs to be in res/layout-xlarge/main.xml

Comment: i am getting the similar screen, after putting the main file in layout-xlarge.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder like this inside the res folder

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size

res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size

res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation